Can I remove my neighbor from showing up in the AirDrop options on MacOS Sonoma
I want to keep the "MacOS Sonoma" in the title because there are hundreds of obsolete Q&A pages or pages about the iOS version of this issue floating around the internet which I have weeded through without finding an answer.
Somebody I assume to be a neighbor regularly shows up in my AirDrop menu, and usually loads up faster than my own devices:

The top option is my other computer, the bottom one is the intrusive device
This obviously creates safety issues, as I do not wish to send a stranger personal documents.
I also wonder if my neighbors and anyone in the neighbourhood can see my face and full name show up when they use AirDrop, which I would obviously prefer to avoid.
I have found an Apple help page explaining how to only show up for friends and contacts in the iOS version of AirDrop, but the desktop computer help page doesn't go into very much details about how to do the same.
A lot of users seem to have a similar complaint about the risks of the current process.
How do I restrict who can connect to my AirDrop and whose machines I can AirDrop to?

The options for who can see his Mac are: Off, Contacts, Everyone. So if your neighbour doesn't have your phone number in their Contacts, send them an image saying "Hey! I can see your Mac!"

@benwiggy And if that doesn't work, there's the option of sending scat porn captioned "stop sharing with everyone on AirDrop!" (Probably use the Impact font.) Although, it might not be entirely their fault. In my experience AirDrop often doesn't work unless you share with everyone. Go figure. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

The plain answer is you don’t get to suppress destinations that show in the AirDrop view on macOS. (This is on par with iOS and iPadOS which also do not limit the devices you see, the only limit is who else sees your device.)
The person you wish to block is the only one that can control their visibility in your recipient list.
You’ll have to choose another tool if you worry you will mistake sending information to the wrong recipient.

Thank you. Would disabling bluetooth on some of the devices limit the problem?

Unlikely @MicroMachine but you can certainly try. Both WiFi and Bluetooth are used for discovery and all the participating devices talk together in an ad-hoc network so you’d need every single device within range to not see that one device to suppress it. In a dense workplace, sometimes there are dozens of recipients and many can be far outside the range of your Bluetooth and WiFi since discovered devices are broadcast across a chain of devices in practice.

Ah ok. Sends more complicated than sending a buut picture to my neighbor for them to remove themselves from my network (since I have no idea how else to reach them...)

They’re not on your network. All the devices talk and make connections. You could shut off every single WiFi router and still have the exact same problem.
